# How do I use tkinter to create a menubar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my first post, so please give feedback to improve if need be.

I am following the tkinter tutorial on [tkdocs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) to learn tkinter. The current [lesson](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html) is attempting to teach me how to create menus, but whenever I run their script, a separate window pops up instead of menu attached the the root window.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
root.option_add('*tearOff', FALSE)
win = Toplevel(root)
menubar = Menu(win)
win['menu'] = menubar

root.mainloop()
```

This pops up as a second window. I'm not sure if I am simply not understanding the material, or if I am doing something wrong. The lessons are written in the mindset that you are using at least python 3 and tkinter 8.6. I have the current Anaconda distribution and it meets both of these requirements.

What am I doing incorrectly to have this code open a separate window as opposed to a menu attached to a window?

Comment: A second window is being created because of the call to `Toplevel()`. That's what it does. The menu is being attached to this newly created window, not the `root`.

Comment: That's what I was wondering. When I originally ran the code, I was creating two windows that didn't have any menu bar options, but after rewriting it, I was able to get it to work how I imagined it was supposed to work. Thank you for your answer, because now I fully understand what is going on.

Comment: That's good to hear and you're welcome. Tkinter is hard to learn primarily because it's so poorly documented. On top of that, it's not very "pythonic" because it's a wrapper around a language and platform independent toolkit / tool command language.

Comment: Thanks. That makes me feel a little better. I like tkinter. It was definitely difficult at first, but I've gotten used to it. I think my main problem with the menubar was that I must have misread that the menubar was going to open on a separate window instead of opening on just one. I'll keep at it though, and thanks for the kind words.

Comment: Here a link to a slightly outdated but still very useful [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) that I've used for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. I misread the tutorial and expected a single window to open up with a menubar and a couple options within that menubar. After messing with the code, I was able to write a script that created the window I originally thought we were going to open. Ultimately, I didn't realize that "TopLevel" would open a separate window, so that was on me. Below is the code that I used to open up a window with the menubar.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.option_add('*tearOff', FALSE)


menubar = Menu(root)
menu_file = Menu(menubar)
menu_edit = Menu(menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_file, label='File')
menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_edit, label='Edit')
root['menu'] = menubar

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks, and I hope this helps someone else understand what is happening if they are learning tkinter as well.